# Azure function v2. Cannot reference dll from nuget

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I am testing how to write a simple azure function that updates an azure sql database.
From VS2017 I made a new Cloud->Azure function v2 with netstandars 2.0. My code is the following:

```
[FunctionName("Activate")]
    public static IActionResult Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequest req, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string serialNumber = req.Query["SerialNumber"];

        try
        {
            var str = "CONNECTION_STRING_FOR AZURE SQL";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(str))
            {
                conn.Open();
                var text = $"UPDATE CLIENT SET ACTIVATION_DATE = '2018-07-23 WHERE SERIAL_NUMBER='{serialNumber}'";

                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(text, conn))
                {
                    // Execute the command and log the # rows affected.
                    var rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    log.Info($"{rows} rows were updated");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new BadRequestObjectResult(ex.Message);
        }

        return serialNumber != null
            ? (ActionResult)new OkObjectResult($"Hello, {serialNumber}")
            : new BadRequestObjectResult("error");
    }
```

It compiles and can be run locally from visual studio:

```
Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: C:\Projects\xxx\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0
Now listening on: http://localhost:7071
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[24/7/2018 8:50:48 πμ] Reading host configuration file 'C:\Projects\xxx\bin\Debug\netstandard2.0\host.json'
[24/7/2018 8:50:48 πμ] Host configuration file read:
[24/7/2018 8:50:48 πμ] {}
[24/7/2018 8:50:48 πμ] Starting Host (HostId=xxx-1133968365, InstanceId=58079dab-xxx-4bb9-aaf5-f24xxx63d3c, Version=2.0.11651.0, ProcessId=11304, AppDomainId=1, Debug=False, ConsecutiveErrors=0, StartupCount=1, FunctionsExtensionVersion=)
[24/7/2018 8:50:48 πμ] Unable to configure java worker. Could not find JAVA_HOME app setting.
[24/7/2018 8:50:48 πμ]
[24/7/2018 8:50:48 πμ] Could not configure language worker Java.
[24/7/2018 8:50:48 πμ]
[24/7/2018 8:50:49 πμ] Generating 1 job function(s)
[24/7/2018 8:50:49 πμ] Found the following functions:
[24/7/2018 8:50:49 πμ] ClientFunctions.Run
[24/7/2018 8:50:49 πμ]
[24/7/2018 8:50:49 πμ] Host initialized (1511ms)
[24/7/2018 8:50:49 πμ] Host started (1616ms)
[24/7/2018 8:50:49 πμ] Job host started
Listening on http://localhost:7071/
Hit CTRL-C to exit...

Http Functions:

        Activate: http://localhost:7071/api/Activate
```

But if I access it through postman I get:

```
[24/7/2018 8:52:58 πμ] Executing 'Activate' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=30cff68d-b8db-446e-bd6d-407990524198)
[24/7/2018 8:52:58 πμ] Executed 'Activate' (Failed, Id=30cff68d-b8db-446e-bd6d-407990524198)
[24/7/2018 8:52:58 πμ] System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Activate. Mik3UpdateFunctionNew: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Could not find or load a specific file. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131621). System.Private.CoreLib: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
```

What I find strange is that each time I start VS2017 and debug the program, a window appears that says downloading azure functions cli tools 2.3.2.

Can someone suggest anything? 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Josh is right. The downloading tip you saw means VS tried to download the latest functin CLI. But actually the downloading failed and it fell back to use the old one, as you can see in your CLI output

```
Starting Host (...,Version=2.0.11651.0,...)
```

It represents the function host version, which is used by CLI `2.0.1-beta.25`. While for now the latest host is `2.0.11933.0` with CLI `2.0.1-beta.33`, i.e.`2.3.2` specified by VS.

Here are some details about how to consume the latest CLI.

1. If you already has the tools folder `%LocalAPPDATA%\AzureFunctionsTools`, delete it to avoid corrupting new tools.
2. On VS menus, Tools->Extensions and Updates, find `Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools`, make sure it's updated to latest version(right now `15.0.40617.0`).
3. If it has been the latest, just restart VS and create a new Azure Function project, wait at the create dialog for VS to download new CLI and templates.

[image]

After a while, we can see the tip change to

[image]

Then you can see `Starting Host (...,Version=2.0.11933.0,...)` while debugging locally and your code should work.

If you still see `2.0.11651.0`, go check whether this folder`%LocalAPPDATA%\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\2.3.2`exists, which contains cli, templates and manifest.json. If the downloading turns out failed, just delete `%LocalAPPDATA%\AzureFunctionsTools` folder and restart VS to download again.

**Update**--how to download tools manually due to poor network.

Open `%LocalAPPDATA%\AzureFunctionsTools\feed.json`, find "2.3.2":{...} content. Download its cli, itemTemplates and projectTemplates.(Need to rename manually after download).

And folder structure in `%LocalAPPDATA%\AzureFunctionsTools\Releases\2.3.2` is like this(same to 2.0.1-beta.25 folder)

[image]

```
cli
--...
templates
--ItemTemplates.nupkg
--ProjectTemplates.nupkg
manifest.json
```

Content of manifest.json

```
{
  "ReleaseName": "2.3.2",
  "CliEntrypointPath":"C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\AzureFunctionsTools\\Releases\\2.3.2\\cli\\func.exe",
  "TemplatesDirectory": "C:\\Users\\UserName\\AppData\\Local\\AzureFunctionsTools\\Releases\\2.3.2\\templates",
  "FunctionsExtensionVersion": "beta",
  "SdkPackageVersion": "1.0.14"
}
```

Comment: Is this path correct %LocalAPPDATA%\AzureFunctionsTools? I have no AzureFunctionsTools folder. The problem is that the download Azure function CLI tool dialog appears every time. So my guess is it cannot be downloded.

Comment: ok sorry, after debuging the app again, this folder appeared there. But inside the folders named: 2.2.2 2.3.1 2.3.2 are empty, while others like 1.3.0 have some folders.

Comment: @gong  Try to restart VS and create a new function project, wait at the create dialog until you see `Updates are ready`.

Comment: I did it. But it does not say Updates are ready, just: Get started with azure functions

Comment: @gong  Check the tools folder again, if 2.3.2 folder is filled with content mentioned, it should work. Or you can try to delete this tools folder and repeat the process to download again.

Comment: I deleted the folder. Re opened VS and said it started downloading 2.3.2. After this dialog box closed I see in AzureFunctionsTools folder an empty 2.3.2 folder and a 2.0.1-beta.25 folder with content inside.

Answer (score 0):

The prompt you are seeing is the Azure Functions extensions for Visual Studio updating your local Azure Functions CLI to the latest version.  There has been a lot of updates recently with the Azure Functions 2.0 preview, especially with how assemblies are being resolved (which falls into the category of your error).  I would encourage you to allow the update to complete. With all the changes occurring as of late with 2.0 it's easy to get some mismatched versions and references between local dev and whats deployed to azure that causes various problems.

If the error still occurs I would suggest opening an issue on Github with the error details as they are looking for feedback in regards to any assembly binding errors that folks are still getting.

Comment: FWIW I reproduced your exact solution in a lab environment with an up to date version of the Azure Functions runtime, updated VS2017, etc.  and was able to run the function in Azure without any error.   So Josh's advice is good.